# Shopify Rest Api - How to get Products by Metafield?

Tags: java, rest, shopify

I am integrating [Shopify](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference) and Java via Rest.

Can I get [Products](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product) by [Metafield](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/metafield)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you need to programatically do that on your own end in your Java application.

You should get *all the products* using `GET /admin/products.json`, then for each product `GET /admin/products/:id/metafields.json` to get every metafield associated with that product, and check on your own end which ones contain the Metafield you want to filter with.